# ClaimsPrincipal vs. IClaimsPrincipal on SharePoint 2013 yield different claims

Tags: .net, sharepoint, wif, claims-based-identity

I am working with a .NET 4.5 WCF service deployed to SharePoint 2013 which uses ADFS to provide custom claims. In the service, I want to extract the claims but I am seeing different results depending on whether I use the System.IdentityModel classes or the Microsoft.IdentityModel classes.  For example:

the following .NET 4.5 code:

```
     var claimsIdentity = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
```

yields ONE item in claimsIdentity.Claims

The 'older' WIF code (using IClaimsPrincipal) below

```
     var claimsPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User as IClaimsPrincipal;
     var claimsIdentity = claimsPrincipal.Identity as IClaimsIdentity;
```

yields 13 claims in claimsIdentity.Claims

How do I access the additional claims that I can see with IClaimsIdentity with the 'new' WIF integration in .NET 4.5.  The problem actually gets worse in that I want to use SecurityTokenDescriptor and cannot do that (in conjunction with IClaimsPrincipal) because of namespace collisions with Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.